# How can I send an Array as a parameter for making body for requesting to the server?

Tags: java, android

I have to send some parameters for making body for requesting to the server.
like this:

```
"UserName":"a.m",
"CityId":"1",
"UserCategories":
[
  {"CategoryId":"ab2d948a-59d1-420d-a29b-8fd88c2d637c"},
  {"CategoryId":"237b6334-3c1f-44ac-bd87-a8e6be0b2144"}
]
```

I don't know how can I send UserCategories as an array.because it is not String that I can send it like other parameters for making body. 
I should have the body like this for getting response:

```
body: {"CityId":"1","UserName":"a.m","UserCategories":[{"UserCategories":"4211f3f4-f506-4458-b96a-0b496515e019"},{"UserCategories":"df7487b3-2043-46ec-97d4-790bfbe83cfc"}]}
```

but now my body is:

```
body: {"CityId":"1","UserName":"a.m","UserCategories":"[{"UserCategories":"4211f3f4-f506-4458-b96a-0b496515e019"},{"UserCategories":"df7487b3-2043-46ec-97d4-790bfbe83cfc"}]"}
```

I'm really confused!

Comment: it's a JSON, and you can pass it as string to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send or receive JSON data, **it is always as a string**. We might speak of JSON objects or JSON arrays, but they are really **string representations** of objects and arrays. You can send the data exactly as you have written here as long as you enclose the entire thing in `{}`. You can send just the array in string form if you wish, exactly as you typed it here. The sender should create a string from the array and the receiver should parse the JSON string into an array. There are many libraries available to help you do this in every language.

Comment: you're right! I had to send my parameters just in String format.So I just manually removed double quotation while I was making body and reached "UserCategory" key. That's it. Thanks a lot:))

Answer (score 0):

your existing UserCategories object is List/Array format after that changed in String format so only its happen

```
"UserCategories":"[
    {"UserCategories":"4211f3f4-f506-4458-b96a-0b496515e019"},
    {"UserCategories":"df7487b3-2043-46ec-97d4-790bfbe83cfc"}]"
```

this is your second-time Json, Here see your **List sent with ""**
like `"UserCategories":"[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that by using retrofit library. You can sent object,arraylist using Retrofit.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body.Check this url to sent Object. You can also sent arraylist under Object In body